# Confining user to one window during a test

Tags: security

Suppose you have written a testing program, to be used in a classroom.

How would you enforce the participants don't use any other software (no Internet, no calculator, no console etc.) during the exam time? Something similiar to "testing mode" in one of TI calculators.

Another possible application: lock players during a chess/bridge computer tournament.

Comment: You may want to ask on serverfault as this is more of a account issue than a programming issue.  The sysadmin can control what services are available to a particular account.

Comment: Or superuser. However, I consider this a programming issue; in my view, anybody should be able to restrict his own priviledges without asking the sysadmin. (Of course this might not be true in many OS's) A testing program could have suid flag set. But how should it lock the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common Windows programming problem.  Do a Google search for "windows kiosk mode".

Answer (score 3):

[Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/07/426294.aspx) would recommend asking "What if Two Programs Did This?"... that is, what would happen if you had two such programs running at the same time?  If the resulting scenario doesn't make sense, you may want to rethink your design.

That being said, if the students are taking the test on computers you (or your IT department) have control over, I think it would be much easier to make a special StudentTest account that only has permissions to run is the testing software, and is denied access to everything else.  That way your testing software isn't 5% test, 95% attempt to keep the student from cheating which probably will have a hole in it at some point anyway.